# JSF Glassfish host

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Is there any Glassfish and JSF 2.0 hosting for free or reaonable prices? I mean something which is good for personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a VPS (virtual private server) account from DreamHost.com for $15/month, install GlassFish, and have your JSF 2.0 app run with unlimited disk space (useful if you also need a MySQL or PostgreSQL or other database) and unlimited traffic.

Answer (score 0):

## No

There isn't a free Java hosting available. There are others like [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/) or [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) that give services for reasonable price and no string attached.